# why do i have to define the same variable again inside the function?

Tags: javascript

this code changes the left position of a div in a loop. I was stuck at making it move for sometime then i tried a line of code.
why do i have to write the code of line 2

```
divPos = numLeft + 'px'
```

again inside the setInterval inside the function to make the div move.

```
let numLeft = 60
let divPos = numLeft + 'px'
let i=0
let reset
let divVar  = document.createElement("div")
divVar.innerHTML = 'car'
divVar.style.position = "relative"
divVar.style.top = '60px'
divVar.style.left = divPos
divVar.style.border = "2px solid blue"
divVar.style.display = "inline-block"
document.body.appendChild(divVar)
changePos()
function changePos(){
  reset = setInterval(()=>{
  i++
  if(i>12){
    clearInterval(reset);
  }
  numLeft+=40
  divPos = numLeft + 'px'
  divVar.style.left = divPos
  },300)
}
```

Comment: the value of divPos has to be updated.  otherwise it is assigned once and then never changes.

Comment: @user120242 is it because its a string ? had it been a number it would have updated the increment without redefining right ?

Comment: no.  the statement `numLeft + 'px'` resolves at that line, and returns the string '60px', which is assigned to divPos.  It does not assign a pointer to numLeft to divPos.

Comment: @user120242 ok thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript primitives are immutable and not assigned by reference.

`let divPos = numLeft + 'px'` assigns a string to `divPos`. That string is created using `numLeft` but then has **nothing further to do with it** so if you later change `numLeft` it has no effect on the value of `divPos`.

Comment: is there a better way to do it than how i did , or its fine ?